# Drag and Drop from a UIPopoverController to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

Anyone please elaborate the concept of drag n drop a uiview object from a UIPopoverController to an underlying UIViewController. This feature is implemented in the 'Keynote' app from the Apple. I read the [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148814/drag-n-drop-from-uipopovercontroller-to-other-uiview) but with this approach my panning stops as soon as I dismiss my popover!

Comment: Could you put your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it works for me....
I took a UIWindow and added as soon as user starts panning in the UIPopoverController I'm adding the dragged view to the new UIWindow. Later with the panning I'm panning the UIWindow rather than moving the view which was added to the UIWindow.